# Databricks merging different tables into one

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, etl

I have 17 source tables each having different columns apart from id and date, which are common. The goal is to merge them into single table. The destination table will be having around 300 columns.

This process needs to run daily to process data incrementally with volume around 50GB.

Source Table 1

```
| id| date | col1 | col2|
|:---- |:------| -----:|-----:|
| 1  | 01.02.2023| somevalue |somevalue|
```

Source Table 2

```
| id| date | col3 | col4|
|:---- |:------| -----:|-----:|
| 1  | 02.02.2023| 34|56|
```

Destination Table 2

```
| id| date | col1 | col2|col3|col4|
|:---- |:------| -----:|-----:|-----:|-----:|
| 1  | 01.02.2023| somevalue |somevalue|34|56|
```

What is the most efficient way of merging them in Databricks using Spark?

Comment: just do join on the shared key?

Comment: Thanks for a tip, I was expecting that will be more complex but I am glad it is so easy 

Answer (score 0):

1. The below code  loads data incrementally  if the source tables (**Employees**, **Customers**, **Products**, **Orders**, and **Books**) are updated with new records over time. The code retrieves the latest date from all the **SOURCE** tables and filters the data based on this date.
2. If new records are added to the source tables with a date greater than the last processed date, only those records will be considered in the merge process and inserted into the "**MergedData**" table.

**MERGE & JOIN Code:**

```
     from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("TableCreation").getOrCreate()
    spark.sql("CREATE  TABLE  IF  NOT  EXISTS MergedData (id  INT, date  DATE, name STRING, age INT, department STRING, salary DOUBLE, email STRING, address STRING, phone_number STRING, price DOUBLE, category STRING, description STRING, customer_id INT, product_id INT, quantity INT, total_price DOUBLE, title STRING, author STRING, genre STRING, publication_date DATE)")     
        latest_date = spark.sql("SELECT  MAX(date) FROM Employees").collect()[0][0]
            employees_data = spark.sql(f"SELECT  *  FROM Employees WHERE  date  >  '{latest_date}'")
            customers_data = spark.sql(f"SELECT  *  FROM Customers WHERE  date  >  '{latest_date}'")
            products_data = spark.sql(f"SELECT  *  FROM Products WHERE  date  >  '{latest_date}'")
            orders_data = spark.sql(f"SELECT  *  FROM Orders WHERE  date  >  '{latest_date}'")
            books_data = spark.sql(f"SELECT  *  FROM Books WHERE  date  >  '{latest_date}'")
            **MERGE Statement**
            merged_data = employees_data.join(customers_data, "id", "outer") \
            .join(products_data, "id", "outer") \
            .join(orders_data, "id", "outer") \
            .join(books_data, "id", "outer") \
            .select(
            employees_data["id"], employees_data["date"].alias("date"), employees_data["name"], employees_data["age"], employees_data["department"], employees_data["salary"],
            customers_data["email"], customers_data["address"], customers_data["phone_number"], products_data["price"], products_data["category"], products_data["description"],
            orders_data["customer_id"], orders_data["product_id"], orders_data["quantity"], orders_data["total_price"], books_data["title"], books_data["author"], books_data["genre"], books_data["publication_date"]
            )
            #NO NULLS
            merged_data = merged_data.fillna({
            "date": "1970-01-01",
            "name": "",
            "age": 0,
            "department": "",
            "salary": 0.0,
            "email": "",
            "address": "",
            "phone_number": "",
            "price": 0.0,
            "category": "",
            "description": "",
            "customer_id": 0,
            "product_id": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "total_price": 0.0,
            "title": "",
            "author": "",
            "genre": "",
            "publication_date": "1970-01-01"
            })
            merged_data.write.mode("append").insertInto("MergedData")
            merged_data.show()
```

[image]

- From the above code  I am Creating a table which have the Incremental data "**MergedData**" using Spark SQL
- The Incremental load is based on the  columns in the MERGE statement.
- The code retrieves the latest date from the "**Employees" table** using the `SQL query SELECT MAX(date) FROM Employees`.
  The latest date is stored in the latest_date variable.
- The latest records from each source table is filtered where the value of date
  column is greater than the latest_date variable.
- We then outer join the filtered data from the source tables on Id column
- Finally we select all the required columns which we will use to
  **UPSERT** data using Merge statement.

This approach allows for ***incremental loading*** of data by processing and inserting only the new or updated records into the target table.

****Note:** All the columns of the destination table should be defined in the **SELECT** and **MERGE** statement. this is to ensure that the merge can do **UPSERT** accordingly. It is a good practice to include all the columns in the **SELECT & MERGE** statement to ensure that only those columns are used in **UPSERT** logic to avoid data being overwritten.*